# Array with multiple symbol string split using regex grouping

Tags: arrays, regex, ruby

I'm trying to figure out the right regex to get the output as expected. It's a part of a bigger problem, and I'm stuck right here. I only want the array elements with the dot(.) notation in them and in the second part after the dot, if there is a symbol (@) group that separately as well.

(Input) `arr = ["ab", "cd.ef", "gh.ij@kl"]`

(Expecting) `[["cd", "ef"], ["gh", "ij", "kl"]]`

I have tried the following regex's to achieve this:

`arr.join(",").scan(/(\w+)\.(\w+)@?(\w+)/)` gives me `[["cd", "e", "f"], ["gh", "ij", "kl"]]`

Also, tried this:

`arr.join(",").scan(/(\w+)\.(\w+)@(\w+)/)` gives me `["gh", "ij", "kl"]]`

Could someone please provide some guidance on how to get the expected outcome?

Comment: right now `/(\w+)\.(\w+)@?(\w+)/` is causing it to capture the "f" separately so that it matches the pattern if you make that last capture group optional  `/(\w+)\.(\w+)@?(\w+)?/` you will get `[["cd", "ef", ""], ["gh", "ij", "kl"]]`

Comment: makes sense, making the part after @ optional is giving me the output i expect. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd break it into two steps. First, you can `grep` all elements with a `"."` character, then `map` each to a `split` version of itself using your two delimiters:

```
arr = ["ab", "cd.ef", "gh.ij@kl"]
arr.grep(/\./).map{|e| e.split(/[@.]/)} # => [["cd", "ef"], ["gh", "ij", "kl"]]
```

If you need to be sure that `@` is permitted in the first section of the split, you could try something like

```
arr = ["foo@bar.baz@garply"]
pat = /([^.]+)\.([^@]+)(?:@(.+))?/
arr.grep(/\./).map{|e| e.scan(pat).flatten.compact} # => [["foo@bar", "baz", "garply"]]
```